# Angular - Pass an Observable as @Input

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component and I want to pass an observable as input

```
<selective [source]="areasService.getSelectAreas()" placeholder="Select Items"></selective>
```

and use it inside the component

```
@Input() source;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchField = new FormControl();
    this.selectiveForm = this.fb.group({
        search: this.searchField
    });
    console.log(this.source);

    this.sub = this.searchField.valueChanges
        .startWith('')
        .debounceTime(200)
        .flatMap(key => this.source)
        .subscribe((result) => {
            this.list = result.json().data.areas;
            this.countItems = this.list.length;
        });

}
```

but I get this error "Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'."

If I inject the service areasService into the component and use it as
    this.areasService.getSelectAreas()
it works fine

But I doesn't work if i pass it as parameter

Comment: The purpose of this is to give to the component the source of data.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that `getSelectAreas` is asynchronous, which means it wouldn't have returned any data when `ngOnInit` is called on the child component. You could get around this by implementing `ngOnChanges`, but that probably would not be the best solution here:

Note that it's generally not a good idea to bind a function call to a component, as it will be called *constantly*. I would either unwrap `areasService.getSelectAreas()` to a value in the controller, or if `areasService.getSelectAreas()` is a `Promise` or `Observable` you can use the `async` pipe to have Angular unwrap it for you, like so:

```
<selective [source]="areasService.getSelectAreas | async" placeholder="Select Items"></selective>
```

If it returns a Promise or Observable, just assign that return value to a variable in the component and bind that instead with the the async pipe.

Comment: I'm sotty buddy, but input properties ARE available in the `ngOnInit`. They aren't in the constructor however.

Comment: You are right, I apologize. I was thinking of `@ViewChild`. It still seems to be a lifecycle issue as I am guessing `getSelectAreas` is async, Edited my answer to show.